# Can't Start App as a Child App in an Umbrella

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My app works fine alone, however, if I tried to run it within an umbrella setup, I get an error:

here is what I did: (at the root of umbrella folder)

```
mix local.rebar
rm -rf deps
rm -rf _build
mix deps.get
iex -S mix phoenix.server

Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

===> Compiling pooler
===> Compiling src/pooler_starter.erl failed
src/pooler_starter.erl:34: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :pooler, "/Users/samir/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths "/Users/samir/Documents/projects/elixir/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile pooler", update it with "mix deps.update pooler" or clean it with "mix deps.clean pooler"
```

although I can start it if I run the command`iex -S mix phoenix.server` at the app folder itself.

here is the `mix.exs` of the umbrella main app:

```
defmodule TrackwareProjects.Mixfile do
use Mix.Project
def project do
    [apps_path: "apps",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps()]
  end
  defp deps do
    []
  end
end
```

the `config.exs` of the umbrella main app:

```
use Mix.Config
import_config "../apps/*/config/config.exs"
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

```
$mix deps.compile
===> Compiling re2
===> Compiling semver
===> Compiling pooler
===> Compiling src/pooler_starter.erl failed src/pooler_starter.erl:34: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :pooler, "/Users/samir/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths "/Users/samir/Documents/projects/elixir/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile pooler", update it with "mix deps.update pooler" or clean it with "mix deps.clean pooler"
```

Comment: can you try `mix deps.compile` after running `mix deps.get`  and tell us what you get ?

Comment: Kindly see edit

Comment: can you give me a snippet of the `mix.exs` file inside umbrella where you used pooler in it, i'll try to generate the problem on my project

Comment: Thanks Ashar, here it is: https://gist.github.com/hopewise/3fc24f2ffc718850c7140c62b060ded6

Comment: did you try adding pooler in applications in `mix.exs` ?